# Call Predicted Amount of a Paraswap Trade Via ABI?

Tags: javascript, web3js

I'm attempting to get the expected rate for a crypto swap using Paraswap.  I'm using a template that has kyberswap already working properly, and I want to use a similar method with Paraswap's ABI to call the same information.  However, I can't find anything that would work.

Paraswap Contract (Human Readable ABI Below):

```
const PARASWAP_FACTORY_ABI = [THE ABI IS TOO BIG TO POST SO IT'S LINKED BELOW ]
const PARASWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS = '0x86969d29F5fd327E1009bA66072BE22DB6017cC6'
const paraswapFactoryContract = new web3.eth.Contract(PARASWAP_FACTORY_ABI, PARASWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS)
```

Para ABI: https://etherscan.io/address/0x86969d29f5fd327e1009ba66072be22db6017cc6#code

What I used as the template

```
const KYBER_RATE_ABI = [THE ABI IS TOO BIG TO POST SO IT'S LINKED BELOW]
const KYBER_RATE_ADDRESS = '0x9AAb3f75489902f3a48495025729a0AF77d4b11e'
const kyberRateContract = new web3.eth.Contract(KYBER_RATE_ABI, KYBER_RATE_ADDRESS)
```

Kyber ABI: https://etherscan.io/address/0x9AAb3f75489902f3a48495025729a0AF77d4b11e#code

How it's called in Kyberswap

```
let kyberResult = await kyberRateContract.methods.getExpectedRate(inputTokenAddress, outputTokenAddress, inputAmount).call()
```

The only thing in the Paraswap ABI that I can see even approaching expected amounts is the getPartnerRegistry function, but that only takes expectedAmount as an input, so doesn't help.

Sorry if the question isn't detailed enough - still learning the technical side of some of this stuff haha.

I read through the ABI, looked for different contract addresses that might be more correct, and attempted calling different methods.

ETA: I'm writing in Javascript.